# finding first and last login in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

[image]

I need to pull the first and last login for each employee for each date listed.  There are about 40 employees and 365 days (give or take).

This formula works but I would have to enter every employee in cell E2 and every date in F2 in order to get the first and last login times.

Is there any way I can do this in one fell swoop and get all first and last for all dates and all employees?

[image]

Comment: This is a perfect case for which pivot tables were invented :) https://support.office.com/en-us/article/create-a-pivottable-to-analyze-worksheet-data-a9a84538-bfe9-40a9-a8e9-f99134456576

Comment: TomJohnRiddle, you think you can give a little more than that

Comment: Can't see anything.  Pictures are blocked here.  What's the code?  I'd point to [MCVE] and especially this line:  _Some people might be prepared to load the parts up, and actually try them to test the answer they're about to post._

Answer (score 2):

You do not need any code to achieve this, a basic Pivot Table would solve your problem:

Being on a cell on your data table, select **Insert | Pivot Table**

Your Pivot data should be automatically selected, and Pivot table should be created as a template.

You may now drag and drop the requested fields from top right to bottom right drawers. In your case Employee and Date fields should go to **Rows** drawer.

After dragging Time field to **Values** drawer, you should click on the Time field in the drawer and:

1. Change the **Summarize the field** by to "Min"
2. And using **Number Format** button on that screen, change the format to Time.

You should now re-drag the Time field to Values and this time summarize the new value as "Max"

At the end, you should be having a view similar to below:
[image: Screenshot]

Comment: For future reference, how do I post my spreadsheet here without posting an image?

Comment: As far as I know, posting spreadsheets is not welcomed since Excel files might contain harmful macros etc. Instead, you may send .CSV files in order to provide sample data. You should upload your file to a file hosting service such as Google Drive and link to this file in your post as: `<a href="http://file">file</a>`.

Comment: You are welcome, you might think to accept my answer if it was helpful for you.